# html textbox posted to php create table columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to php and trying to learn. This example is not going live!

I have a html textbox and posted to php. I am trying to break the string up using the explode  function and want to add this seperate strings into my select database and table as the database "columns". any help or advice would be great thanks

```
$getMessage = $_POST["dbMessages"];
    $questions = $_POST["dbMessagesName"];
    $answers = $_POST["dbMessages"];
    $combined = array_combine($questions, $answers);

$dbConnectionT = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbName);

        // create loop to assign input boxes together
        foreach($combined as $question => $answer)
        {

            // create the tables and columns from the message text box
                    $sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE " . $question . "(
                                        ADD THE ANSWER AS COLUMN NAMES
                                        )";

                    $answerSplit = explode(" ", implode($getMessage));



                    // if the connection and sql query is true echo for debugging   
                    if ($dbConnectionT->query($sqlCreateTable) == TRUE) {
                    echo "created table";

                    print "{$question} = {$answer} ";

                    echo "</br>";
                    }

   }
```

Above is the code, answer are all in the same text box seperated by white space, I am trying to add all the answers as columns in the created tables from the form.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have a specific question? Have you tried any code yet? This is too broad of a question. You need to provide more details/code.

Comment: Hi, just added the code

Comment: The code makes it a little better, but the question is still not clear. Are you asking for help with the code, ie. adding the column names to the query, or are you asking if this is a good database/table design?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I know the database design is not good. It is a little programming challenge i have to do, nothing to do with databases design. I am trying to add the columns in the table based on the answer, when i loop through the answer. The table is created using $question from one input textbox and the answer is in another text input box, although it can be - answera answerb answerc so i need to split them up and add them to the same table. Thanks

Comment: well columns need more than just names, they need datatype, size, etc. are you gathering that info as well or will you be using default/standard attributes?

Comment: they will all just be VARCHAR(60) .. Just for this purpose

Comment: If all your column names are in a string, separated by spaces, there is no need to use explode. Just replace the spaces with `VARCHAR(60),` -> `$columns = "\`".str_replace(" ", "\` VARCHAR(60), \`", $answers)."\` VARCHAR(60)";` Then you could use this in your query -> `$sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE " . $question . "( ". $columns. " )";`

Comment: That works, although now when i have two input boxes, it does not add both the tables, it only adds the last one using dynamic input boxes

Comment: Sorted Thank you very much!! Thank you!! Please post your answer as a answer so i can add a point!! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per comments-

If all your column names are in a string, separated by spaces, there is no need to use explode. Just replace the spaces with `VARCHAR(60),`

```
$columns = "`".str_replace(" ", "` VARCHAR(60), `", $answers)."` VARCHAR(60)"; 
// wrap column names with ` to prevent issues with reserved words
```

Then you could use this in your query

```
$sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE " . $question . "( ". $columns. " )";
```